# Real time signal processing in frequency domain

Tags: frequency-domain, delay

i'm doing realtime signal processing simulation.

it could be simple question.

if i multiply input L sample fft and M block filter in frequency domain and i do ifft
the output come out when index is L+1+M/2 ??

Comment: I think maybe more explanation needed.

Comment: i correct L sample of input data and FFT and i have M tap fir filter. and i multiply (linear convolution) and ifft and i get L sample of filtered input data. what is total time delay if there is no computational time??  (ex, fft or ifft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this methodically. Typically frequency domain processing has the following parameters:

1. **Hop Size**, $H$: number of samples you advance between frames
2. **Window Length** $W$: number of samples taken from the input and multiplied with a window (which can be rectangular in some cases).
3. **Filter Length** $M$: number of taps in the filter. This can be potentially chopped up into multiple blocks as well, but we skip this for simplicity
4. **FFT length** $N$: number of samples for each FFT

Here is the order of operation for overlap-add. Overlap-save slightly different but the same principal applies

1. Wait for $H$ samples to arrive.
2. Cascade the new samples with old samples until you have a frame of size $W$. Save new samples for the next frame(s). Discard what you don't need anymore.
3. Apply window
4. Zero pad to $N$ samples. This needs to satisfy $N \geq W+M-1$ to avoid time domain aliasing.
5. Multiply with the FFT of the filter (also zero-padded to length $N$)
6. Inverse FFT. This results in $N$ time domain samples.
7. Take the first $H$ samples, add the overlap from previous frame(s) and output them.
8. Cascade the remaining $H-N$ frames with your existing overlap (and keep as much as you need from the total)

There may or may not be a reconstruction window as well, but that's typically the same length than the analysis window in step 3.

Let's assume you have a sampling rate of $F_s = 48kHz$, a hop size of 512, and a window and filter length of 1024. FFT length would need to be at least 2047, but let's do 2048 for simplicity.

The frame rate is determined by your hop size, so you will have $F_s/H = 93.75$ frames per second or one frame roughly every $10ms$.

Every $10ms$ you will consume 512 new samples and calculate 2048 result samples and output 512 samples. The result samples will be spread out over 4 output frames.

The total latency is twice the hop size or about $20ms$ in this example. You need one frame time to accumulate the input and a another frame time to process it.

Comment: Thank you very much. maybe i confused between fir group delay and frame delay... One more time.... first 10ms is frame delay and last 10ms is....what? just express computational delay? i'm sorry about misunderstand